# Wick's theorem on $C_\ell$ : where does factor $\dfrac{1}{2\ell+1}$ come from?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, covariance, wick-theorem

Just a question that bothers me.

This concerns Wick's theorem, which my book gives as:

> *Wick's theorem:*
>
> If $G = (G_1, \dots, G_n)$ is a centered gaussian multivariate random variable ($\langle G_1 \rangle = \dots = \langle G_n \rangle = 0$), then $$
> \langle G_1 \cdots G_m \rangle = \begin{cases} 0 & m \text{ odd} \\ \langle G_1 G_2 \rangle \cdots \langle G_{m-1} G_m \rangle + \text{permutations} & m \text{ even}\end{cases}
> $$
> where the permutations run over all ways to group $1 \cdots m$ into pairs.
>
> Example:  for $m = 4$ we have $\langle G_1 G_2 G_3 G_4 \rangle = \langle G_1 G_2 \rangle \langle G_3 G_4 \rangle + \langle G_1 G_3 \rangle \langle G_2 G_4 \rangle + \langle G_1 G_4 \rangle \langle G_2 G_3 \rangle.$

I would like to demonstrate that for Gaussian observables, we have the following expression for the covariance:

> $$
> \operatorname{Cov}\left(\hat{C}_{\ell}^{W X}, \hat{C}_{\ell^{\prime}}^{Y Z}\right)=\frac{C_{\ell}^{W Z} C_{\ell}^{X Y}+C_{\ell}^{W Y} C_{\ell}^{X Z}}{2 \ell+1} \delta_{\ell, \ell^{\prime}}$$ In particular, for a single observable we have
> $$
> \operatorname{Cov}\left(\hat{C}_{\ell}^{YY}, \hat{C}_{\ell^{\prime}}^{Y Y}\right)=\frac{2 (C_{\ell}^{YY})^2}{2 \ell+1} \delta_{\ell, \ell^{\prime}}\quad(1)
> $$

1. I would like to know in these 2 last expressions where the factor "$(2\ell+1)$" comes from in the denominator.

Indeed, Wick's theorem only shows sums of pairs of $C_\ell$ but this factor "$\dfrac{1}{2\ell+1}$" does not appear in the sum of permutations.

If anyone could help me, that would be nice.

**EDIT 1** :

2. In my case, we make the approximation that $C_\ell$ is Gaussian (true excepted for low $\ell$ (from cosmology context)).

By the way, we use the following estimator for power spectrum :

$$\hat{C}_{\ell}^{X Y}=\frac{1}{2 \ell+1} \sum_{m} a_{\ell m}^{X}\left(a_{\ell m}^{Y}\right)^{*}$$

The first step is to compute the covariance of this estimator. For this, one has to use Wick's theorem.

but I can't conclude from this point to make appear the $\frac{1}{2 \ell+1}$ factor in this expression :

$$\operatorname{Cov}\left(\hat{C}_{\ell}^{W X}, \hat{C}_{\ell^{\prime}}^{Y Z}\right)=\frac{C_{\ell}^{W Z} C_{\ell}^{X Y}+C_{\ell}^{W Y} C_{\ell}^{X Z}}{2 \ell+1} \delta_{\ell, \ell^{\prime}}\quad(1)$$

If someone could show me the calculus to get (1) ...

**EDIT 2:** to infer the expression (1), I don't know if I have to consider :

$$E[a_{\ell m} a_{\ell' m'} a_{\ell'' m''} a_{\ell''' m'''}]$$

or

$$E[C_{\ell} C_{\ell'} C_{\ell''} C_{\ell'''}]$$

since in the second case, I can consider for high multipoles (CMB) that $C_{\ell}$ is assumed to be Gaussian.

By the way, Could anyone give me a track to make appear in this demonstration the following quantity (assimilated to a "cross" angular power spectrum") :

$$\hat{C}_{\ell}^{X Y}=\frac{1}{2 \ell+1} \sum_{m} a_{\ell m}^{X}\left(a_{\ell m}^{Y}\right)^{*}$$

From this, How to conclude about (1)

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: As you have given no context on what the $C_\ell$ are, or the meaning of $\ell$, it is currently quite difficult to answer the question in its current form.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero .This is a context of cosmology : $C_\ell$ are the spherical harmonics from Legendre decomposition and $\ell$ is the multipole.

Comment: well you should edit your question to include this, and also so clarify what is $\hat C_\ell^{YZ}$ since spherical harmonics are usually denoted $Y_{\ell}^m(\theta,\phi)$.

Comment: The $C_\ell$ are not Gaussian distributed. They are $\chi^2$ distributed (since $C_\ell$ for a given $\ell$ is the sum over $m$ of the squares of the $a_{\ell m}$, which are Gaussian). There is a normalization factor of $1/(2\ell+1)$ relating the $a_{\ell m}$ and $C_\ell$. Carefully accounting for this normalization factor, and the fact that the variance of a $\chi^2$ distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom is $2k$, gives you the result you want.

Comment: The expectation value of the product of 2 $C_\ell$'s is the variance of the $\chi^2$ distribution. There are more details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution

Comment: @Andrew . Thanks for your quick answer. Unfortunately, I have to compute the expectation of the product of 2 $C_\ell$. So If I write : 


$$E\bigg[C_{\ell}\,C_{\ell}^{\prime}\bigg]= E\bigg[\bigg(\dfrac{1}{2\ell+1}\bigg)^{2}\,\sum_{m=-\ell}^{+\ell}\,a_{\ell m}^2\,\sum_{m^{\prime}=-\ell}^{+\ell}a\prime_{\ell m^{\prime}}^2\bigg] = \bigg(\dfrac{1}{2\ell+1}\bigg)^2\,E\bigg[\sum_{m=-\ell}^{+\ell}\,a_{\ell m}^2\bigg]\,E\bigg[\sum_{m^{\prime}=-\ell}^{+\ell}\,a\prime_{\ell m^{\prime}}^2\bigg]=1$$

but I can't conclude from this point. Where is my mistake ?

Comment: @Andrew . Could you see please where is my error in my reasoning of **UPDATE** above ? Regards

Comment: @youpilat13 If you don't want to directly use the $\chi^2$ results, you can derive them by applying Wick's theorem to the $a_{\ell m}$. To apply Wick's theorem, you need to evaluate expectation values of Gaussian random variables. The $C_\ell$'s are not Gaussian. The $a_{\ell m}$ are. The basic expectation value you need to evaluate is a four point function $E[a_{\ell m} a_{\ell' m'} a_{\ell'' m''} a_{\ell''' m'''}]$. In your comment evaluating $E[C_\ell C_{\ell'}]$ you implicitly used $E[a_{\ell m}^2 a_{\ell' m'}^2] = E[a_{\ell m}^2] E[a_{\ell' m'}^2]$, which is false. Use Wick's theorem.

Comment: You've also got to use the linearity of expectation, $E[\sum_m a_{\ell m}^p] = \sum_m E[a_{\ell m}^p]$.

Comment: @Andrew . Please could you help me, I can't manage to conclude with the computation of $$E[a_{\ell m} a_{\ell' m'} a_{\ell'' m''} a_{\ell''' m'''}]$$